# Running code outside the "it" block breaks my Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to write some test cases (first time) using *jasmine*

```
describe("Widget App core logic", function () {
  WAPP.widgets = [];
```

addwidget will add a widget in my WAPP.widgets array

```
  WAPP.addWidget('testRecord', 'testRecordContent');
  it("added", function () {
        expect(WAPP.widgets.length).toEqual(1);
    });
```

Remove widget will remove same widget

```
  WAPP.removeWidget('1'); 
  it("record removed correctly", function () {
        expect(WAPP.widgets.length).toEqual(0);
    })
```

After writing second spec my first spec fails as it shows *WAPP* .widgets is empty. even though at the time of first spec there is a value in *WAPP*.widgets

Comment: There are guaranties that your code runs synchronously? What jasmine documentation say about this? What is your complete code? The two `it` calls are inside the describe function?

Comment: no remove and add both it calls are in different describe

Comment: So, try to use them in the same describe. It seems that it should be used this way (I saw the docs).

Comment: doesn't work. can you point me to docs

Comment: http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you shouldn't have test code outside of `it`. The code outside of the `it` is ran once before the execution of all the test case. What is probably happening in your case is that you delete all the widget before the test even starts.

What your test code should look like is this :

```
describe("Widget App core logic", function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    WAPP.widgets = [];
  });

  it("added", function () {
    WAPP.addWidget('testRecord', 'testRecordContent');
    expect(WAPP.widgets.length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it("record removed correctly", function () {
    WAPP.addWidget('1', '1');
    WAPP.removeWidget('1'); 
    expect(WAPP.widgets.length).toEqual(0);
  })    

});
```

Do note that your test code should be self-contained, all the initialization should be done inside the `it` or with `beforeEach`.

Comment: Actually this is the best advice EVER! I can't believe how long i have been playing around, moving code and wasting my time in docs. Suddenly everything works as expected. Make sure everything is in `it`