# jasmine test method is being called as asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test a code snippet using jasmine but its always passing due to Jasmine's it method is being called as asynchronously. Here is my test code

```
function outer() {
    it("| --- BEFORE OUTER ---|", function() {
        expect("yes").toEqual("yes");
    });
    it("outer() is in scope", function() {
        expect(typeof outer).toEqual('function');
    });
    it("inner() is in scope", function() {
        expect(typeof inner).toEqual('function');
    });
    it("a is in scope", function() {
        console.log('Why this is running after');
        expect(typeof a).toEqual('number');
    });
    it("b is in scope", function() {
        expect(typeof b).toEqual('number');
    });
    it("c is in scope", function() {
        expect(typeof c).toEqual('number');
    });
    console.log("This is running first");
    var a = 1;

    function inner() {}
    var b = 2;
    if (a == 1) {
        var c = 3;
    }
}
outer();
```

how to fix this? I want to run it's callback method immediately before running the declaration statements like var a = 1;

Comment: Side note: `var` and `function` declarations are always hoisted -- treated as though they were written at the top of the scope anyways. It's only the initializations / assignments, such as `a = 1` and `c = 3`, that remain where they're written. Though, `inner` will always refer to a `function` within `outer`.

Comment: Possibly related: [Running code outside the “it” block breaks my Jasmine test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227922/running-code-outside-the-it-block-breaks-my-jasmine-test)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I have debugged my code step by step, before the it method a is undefined but inside it's callback function a has value 1. So the callback function is running after executing the outer() method completely.